# How to configure NixOS with nvidia on an Optimus laptop?

Tags: linux, laptop, drivers, graphics-card

I have an Acer Aspire E15 laptop model E5-572G-38HC with integrated intel graphics card and a nvidia GeForce 840M card. I enabled bumblebee in my configuration.nix but only the intel card is working and when i look at the list of modules, the nvidia module is missing.
When installing bumblebee i noticed that the installation process downloaded the nvidia driver but for some reason the module does not load.

This is my configuration.nix:
http://pastebin.com/2kepcGfr

and my hardware-configuration.nix:
http://pastebin.com/57wCmzN8

What am I doing wrong ?
Just a mention, the nouveau driver doesn't work at all, i think it does not support this model of nvidia card.

Comment: I modified the file harware-configuration.nix to boot the module but it still does not work. I can do "modprobe nvidia" and it loads the module but it does not take effect. The rendering driver is still the intel one. Here is the modification: http://pastebin.com/p4NUjzcy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that bumblebee is working fine, the configuration is actually good instead I did not understand how bumblebee works. Bumblebee keeps the intel card allways working for the X session, if I want to play a game on my nvidia card I have to manualy launch it with optirun for example: `optirun glxgears`. You can actually see that the nvidia card is running with `optirun glxgears -info`.
I was expecting for the bumblebee to decide automatically when to run a game on nvidia. The ArchWiki says:

> "In Windows, the way that Optimus works is NVIDIA has a whitelist of applications that require Optimus for, and you can add applications to this whitelist as needed. When you launch the application, it automatically decides which card to use.
>   To mimic this behavior in Linux, you can use libgl-switcheroo-git."

At the moment there is no switcherro in NixOs package repository...
So everyting actually works '*as is supposed to*' but not '*as expected to*'. I can't launch a steam game with optirun... but this is another issue.

Comment: After so many strugles with NixOS trying to launch a Steam game with  Primus I finally managed to make it work with help from someone from IRC channel #nixos. My problem was that when setting in Launch Options: primusrun %command% , the game would not start. Steam needed to be installed from an overlay with the option: withPrimus = true. Here is my conversation from IRC in hope to be of some help to you: https://pastebin.com/jL8QLLnj